# How to receive push notifications on my iPhone with IOS 16.4

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, notifications

Hello everyone I hope you are well recently there was an update on iOS that now allows you to receive push notifications from a site on iPhone with the version IOS 16.4

Here is a piece of code that I wanted to try on my iPhone however I have no popup to display when I click on the button my iPhone has well the update 16.4 in the settings of my iPhone I gave him access to receive external notifications

Settings>Safari > Advanced>Experimental Features> (accept push api)

I would like to know if someone succeeded in setting up push notifications on safari on iPhone please
Here is my code below

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="notify-btn">Click me </button>
</body>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

main.js

```
document.querySelector(".notify-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

  Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
    if (result !== "granted") {
      console.log("No notification permission granted!");
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Button clicked");
      new Notification("This is a notification", {
        body: "This is the body of the notification",
        icon:
          "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-brand-logo-2/512/medium-512.png",
      });
    }
  });
});
```

result on my Mac
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLzhD.png)